# Rewriting Magento Gift Card observer function

Tags: magento

When I need to rewrite a function in an observer located in the Enterprise section, how will that rewrite bit look like on config.xml.

is it something like this?

```
<global>
    <models>
        <enterprise>
            <rewrite>
                <giftcard>Custom_GiftCard_Model_Observer</giftcard>
            </rewrite>
        </enterprise>
    </models>
</global>
```

My class is declared as follow:
class Custom_GiftCard_Model_Observer extends Enterprise_GiftCard_Model_Observer {
    .....
}

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I don't have an enterprise development environment setup at the moment, so this is untested, but it should work as described.

If you look at the Gift Card configuration in

```
app/code/core/Enterprise/GiftCard/etc/config.xml
```

You can grep about and discover the class alias for the gift card observer

```
<class>enterprise_giftcard/observer</class>
```

So, with a class alias of `enterprise_giftcard/observer` you have a model group name of `enterprise_giftcard`, and a model class name of `observer`.

In your module's configuration file, first you'll create an area for model configuration

```
<global>
    <models>

    </models>
</global>
```

Then, you'll add the group name of the class you want to rewrite, `enterprise_giftcard`

```
<global>
    <models>
        <enterprise_giftcard>
        </enterprise_giftcard>
    </models>
</global>
```

Then, you'll add a node saying you want to rewrite the a single class in this group

```
<global>
    <models>
        <enterprise_giftcard>
            <rewrite>
            </rewrite>
        </enterprise_giftcard>
    </models>
</global>
```

The, you'll add a node indicating WHICH class in the group you wish to rewrite, using the name portion of the class alias (`observer`)

```
<global>
    <models>
        <enterprise_giftcard>
            <rewrite>
                <observer></observer>
            </rewrite>
        </enterprise_giftcard>
    </models>
</global>
```

And finally, within this node, you'll add a text node that's the name of your new class.

```
<global>
    <models>
        <enterprise_giftcard>
            <rewrite>
                <observer>Custom_GiftCard_Model_Observer</observer>
            </rewrite>
        </enterprise_giftcard>
    </models>
</global>
```

You can test your rewrite by instantiating the observer directly, and checking its class name

```
$model = Mage::getModel('enterprise_giftcard/observer');
var_dump(get_class($model));
```

Comment: Well description i'm ur follower.

Comment: That did the job, thanks. I was pulling my hair out, because I forgot the basics!

Comment: Hi @Alan Do we need to add <frontend>  <events> sections also to config.xml to work the override to work as I see in following tutorial 
https://www.atwix.com/magento/overriding-observers/